# Unique Values in the dataset

Tags: python, dataframe, function, unique-values

When you have a data frame that you have created from importing and loading a CSV file and I want to start Data Exploration.
I have started Checking for Missing Values and I have decided to deal with these different missing values in a different way starting from dropping some rows or even replacing some.

Now when I want to start checking for unique values I checked for the duplicated and I hade the result ( 0 Duplicates) Now when checked for Unique values I have unique Values [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrYQT.png)

My question :
What is the best way to deal with these unique values? should I remove them all? or what exactly I have to do with them.

I am still new to the Data exploration field and I have my task to be done with so all your help and suggestions are really so appreciated.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have a dataset that I need to do a Data exploration for it and visualization and analysis  So I found the missing values and handled all missing values and now in the unique values. So after finding out the unique values should I do a specific thing to them or just find them out and keep them in my dataset?

Comment: It is difficult to say what you could do with the unique values without a description of the analysis or end result you are expecting.

Comment: If you want it to make a prediction with the data then delete those columns that will not contribute to you in the prediction.

In general I find no reason to hold a column whose entire information is the same